# Python C stderr with AllocConsole

Tags: python, c, windows, stdout

I am attempting to capture output of an error, whose output is produced by PrErr_Print()

However, no output is appearing. Here is what I have tried, via this thread:

[Redirect Embedded Python IO to a console created with AllocConsole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698439/redirect-embedded-python-io-to-a-console-created-with-allocconsole)

```
PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
PyObject* io = PyImport_ImportModule("io");
PyObject* pystdout = PyObject_CallMethod(io, "open", "ss", "CONOUT$", "wt");
PyObject_SetAttrString(sys, "stderr", pystdout);
if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
    printf("Could not redirect python stderr to stdout\n");
    PyErr_Print();
    extensions_destroy();
    return 0;
}
```

And the creation of the console

```
/**
 * Enable debug console
 */
void debug_enable( void ) {
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    printf("Debug mode enabled.\n");
}
```

I have also attempted to redirect python stderr to it's stdout to no avail.

Comment: Python 2.7, And yes, the call is shown in the second block of code... Not python stderr and stdout work perfectly

Comment: Ah I see, sorry... Yeah debug_enable is called well before python is initialized

Comment: The debug console works perfectly. It's only the output of PyErr_Print that is not visible. If I compile with a console, it works

Comment: `io.open` in text mode requires `unicode` strings, but `PyFile_WriteString` writes regular `str` byte strings. You can use unbuffered binary mode `PyObject_CallMethod(io, "open", "ssi", "CONOUT$", "wb", 0);`. Or just use a regular 2.x `file` like in the linked answer.

Comment: That worked, thank you

Comment: I think it's simpler to use `PyObject* pystdout = PyFile_FromString("CONOUT$", "w"); PyFile_SetBufSize(pystdout, 0);` instead of using `io.open`. I wish there were a simple way to execute the `freopen` function of Python's CRT. Then you wouldn't need any of this. You could just fix up Python's C `stderr` before calling `Py_Initialize`.